# Is there a library or tool in Scikit learn for spliting a dataset of sub-classes into Train/Test sets in folders

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, deep-learning, dataset, artificial-intelligence

I have a an **unbalanced** **8 classes** dataset which have ***4 sub-classes*** in each class, and i want to split it into folders of Test/Train sets, the dataset is like this:

```
Dataset
   |------ Class A
   |  |---------Sub-Class 1
   |  |---------Sub-Class 2
   |  |---------Sub-Class 3
   |  |---------Sub-Class 4
   |
   |------ Class B
   |  |---------Sub-Class 1
   |  |---------Sub-Class 2
   |  |---------Sub-Class 3
   |  |---------Sub-Class 4
   |
   |------ Class C
   |  |---------Sub-Class 1
   |  |---------Sub-Class 2
   |  |---------Sub-Class 3
   |  |---------Sub-Class 4
   |
   |------ Class D
   |  |---------Sub-Class 1
   |  |---------Sub-Class 2
   |  |---------Sub-Class 3
   |  |---------Sub-Class 4
   |
   |------ Class E
   |  |---------Sub-Class 1
   |  |---------Sub-Class 2
   |  |---------Sub-Class 3
   |  |---------Sub-Class 4
   |
   |------ Class F
   |  |---------Sub-Class 1
   |  |---------Sub-Class 2
   |  |---------Sub-Class 3
   |  |---------Sub-Class 4
   |
   |------ Class G
   |  |---------Sub-Class 1
   |  |---------Sub-Class 2
   |  |---------Sub-Class 3
   |  |---------Sub-Class 4
   |
   |------ Class K
   |  |---------Sub-Class 1
   |  |---------Sub-Class 2
   |  |---------Sub-Class 3
   |  |---------Sub-Class 4
```

So, i am looking for an effcient and professional tool that can help me in spliting the dataset into folder of Train/Test sets.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using a [train_test_split](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html) function from the sklearn library. It has the parameter - **stratify**. For this parameter, you can specify a few columns from the dataset for the stratification.

For example:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(Dataset, 
                                                    Dataset['Class'],
                                                    test_size=0.1, 
                                                    stratify=Dataset[['Sub-Class']])
```

Comment: i don't want them as arrays, because i am using **.flow_from_directory** keras function, and i don't have **a lot of Ram** to use that method.

Comment: You can try to add one more step:
* build a dataframe ['Class', 'Sub-Class', 'real_path']
* split the dataframe using `train_test_split`
* copy the files into the train or test directory accordingly

Comment: Ok i will give it a try

Answer (score 0):

You can use train_test_split() function from sklearn.model_selection. Here is a example of spliting the data into 20% test and 80%train

X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split(x,y, test_size=0.2)

Comment: i don't want them as arrays, because i am using **.flow_from_directory** keras function, and i don't have **a lot of Ram** to use that method.

Answer (score 0):

You can use split-folders a library to split the folders into train, test and validation folders or just train and validation folders. The link is given below you can check it out

https://pypi.org/project/split-folders/

Comment: Please do not just post a link but include the essential part of the solution in your answer.